# How to create this text effect in Illustrator? (one word, 2 different colours)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, transparency, clipping-mask

How would you create this effect (below) in Illustrator with the coloured text and transparent text over the coloured shape?

I've tried using clipping masks and even the live paint bucket tool (which I just discovered) but nothing is working.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- place the shape and the text as required
- convert the text to paths
- select the text and the shape
- apply the Divide options from the Pathfinder palette
- use the direct selection tool or ungroup the result to colour each part as required

Comment: I totally forgot about the Divide tool, thanks for the help.